# Running time of my Collatz (3n+1) Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

So I want to figure out what is the running time of my algorithm

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int steps = 0;

    void collatz(int n)
    {
        if(n % 2 == 0)
        {
            n = n/2;
            steps++;
        }
        else
        {
            n = 3*n + 1;
            steps++;
        }

        if(n==1)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        { 
            collatz(n);
        }
    }

    int main () 
    {
        int x = 0;
        int *L = new int[x];

        cout << "Hello world " << endl; 

        for(int n = 1;n <= 27;n++)
        {
            collatz(n);
            L[x] = steps;
            x++;
            steps = 0;
        } 

        cout << "|";
        for(int i = 0;i < x;i++)
        {
            cout <<  L[i] << "|";
        }
        cout << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

So Basically I have a for loop that iterate n times O(n) and for each n I call the collatz function which is a recursive function. We can say that T(n) = 3n+1 if n is odd and T(n) = n/2 of n is even we can consider 3n+1 because it's larger than n/2 but then T(n)= 3n+1  but then what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anyone knows the answer. Actually, your program may even never terminate, as it has never been proven that `n` will always reach the value `1`, althrough it is believed that it does (this is the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Statement_of_the_problem))

Comment: hahaha,So it's not bounded ? Can I change my algorithm to make it bounded ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. But if you want to be sure it is bounded, you will have to change the whole behavior of the program…

Comment: when your number becomes  4 then it run in a loop, for better understanding https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=094y1Z2wpJg .

Answer (score -1):

John Horton Conway proved in 1972 that a natural generalization of the Collatz problem is algorithmically undecidable, so no bounding is possible on your function (for now).

Comment: While the reference is nice, a proof that a generalization is undecidable proves nothing about a specific instance. Otherwise the Collatz conjecture wouldn't be an open problem.